# Does the change in velocity of a body due to a space-depending force depend on the initial velocity of the body?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Let's say, for simplicity, that we have a line, and over a segment $AB$ of this line is being exerted a constant force $F$. A body $P$ travels from $A$ to $B$. My question is: does the change in velocity of the body measured in $B$, depend on the velocity of $P$ measured in $A$?

For example: $P_1$ has an initial velocity $v_1 = 1$ m/s, $P_2$ has $v_2 = 2$ m/s (we assume that $F$ is s.t. both the bodies reach the point $B$). Calling $v_{f_1}, v_{f_2}$ the velocity of the bodies in $B$, is it true that $v_1 -v_{f_1}=v_2-v_{f_2}$?

I think it is, but i can't mathematically figure out why.

Comment: Are you familiar with the kinematical equations?

Comment: Yes, I do. I just don't know how to apply them in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is yes, the final velocity will depend on the value of the initial velocity. Referring to basic classical mechanics, just think about what is the action of a force on a body? It gives an acceleration in a certain direction, i.e., it defines how the velocity will change through time. But it defines how it changes, not the exact values, so the final value will depend on a previous one through the rule of change given by the applied force.

Imagine a point particle with mass $m$ that follows the trajectory $\vec{x}(t)$, and that a force $F$ is applied to it along the trajectory (let's assume that this force depends on the particle's position only). Then, Newton's second law tell us that
$$
\dfrac{d^2 \vec{x}}{dt^2} = \dfrac{d\vec{v}}{dt} = \dfrac{\vec{F}(\vec{x})}{m}\ .
$$
By solving this differential equation, you can get a general description for the velocity $\vec{v}(t)$ of the particle along its trajectory, but you must provide and initial condition for the velocity, let's say $\vec{v}(t_0) = \vec{v}_0$, in order to get the exact evolution of $\vec{v}(t)$.

For example, restrict the problem to one dimension in the $x$ axis, with a constant force along all the movement, so the particle gets a constant acceleration $a = F/m$. Then you have
$$
\dfrac{dv}{dt} = a \quad\Rightarrow\quad \int dv = a \int dt \quad\Rightarrow\quad v(t) = at + A\ ,
$$
where $A$ is some constant to be determined. Let's give it an initial condition for $v$, such that $v(t = 0) = v_0$, then
$$
v_0 = A \quad\Rightarrow\quad v(t) = at + v_0\ .
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I knew the final velocity is generally dependent on the initial velocity. What I am not sure about is: if a body $P_1$ has, for example, an initial velocity at $A$ of 2 m/s, and at the point B is measured a velocity of 1 m/s, does this imply that a second body, $P_2$, with an initial velocity of 10 m/s, will have a final velocity of 9 m/s? In other words: is the total acceleration along the path $AB$ the same, regardless of $v_0$? The reason I am asking this is that, intuitively, in the second case the body spends less time within the segment of space.

Comment: @Due.Berto In that case, it is easy to see that $P_2$ won't decrese its velocity by 1 m/s as $P_1$ does, and the reason is related to what you say. If we assume that both have the same mass, and that the force only depends on position (for example electromagnetic force also depends on velocity), both will experience the same acceleration and experience the same rate for increasing/decreasing its velocity. But having different velocities at $A$, they will waste different times on going to $B$, and one will have suffered the rate of change in velocity more time than the other when arriving $B$.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you look into the kinematical equations again as it is quite straightforward to provide mathematical basis to your question through them. The standard three equations of motion are applicable under constant acceleration, which your question satisfies with constant force acting on the body.

Now in the example provided by you,

> if a body $_1$ has, for example, an initial velocity at  of 2 m/s, and at the point B is measured a velocity of 1 m/s, does this imply that a second body, $_2$, with an initial velocity of 10 m/s, will have a final velocity of 9 m/s ?

Assuming $P_1$ and $P_2$ to have equal masses, their accelerations will be equal to some constant $a$. Since we know the initial and final velocities of $P_1$, we can use the third equation of motion as:
$$v_1^2-u_1^2=2as$$
where $v_1$, $u_1$ and $s$ are the final and initial velocities and the length of path AB respectively. The same equation can be applied to $P_2$ as($v_2$ and $u_2$ being the final and initial velocities of $P_2$):
$$v_2^2 - u_2^2 = 2as$$
From here we can conclude,$$v_1^2 - u_1^2 = v_2^2 - u_2^2$$
It is clear from here that it's not the difference in final and initial velocities that will be equal for two identical bodies moving along the same path under the same acceleration, but the difference in squares of the final and initial velocities of the two bodies. This is consistent with your intuition that the body with the higher initial velocity will spend less time along the path, and thus have a lower change in velocity.